# THREEjs Raycaster interceptObject issues

Tags: javascript, 3d, three.js

Hi so I'm creating rays from vertice to vertice and seeing if they intercept a plane geometry. If they do then I take the point of interception and push it to an array of vertices. However I'm not sure if I'm implementing raycaster correctly as this code snippet is not doing what I intended it to. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
    var vertlen = geometry.vertices.length;
  var vertarray = geometry.vertices;
  var planey = plane.vertices[0].y; 
  var final = new THREE.Geometry();
  var intersects;
  var intersectpoint;

  var raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster();
  for (var i = 0; i < vertlen; i++){
    for (var k = 0; k < vertlen; k++){
        raycaster.set(vertarray[i], vertarray[k]);
      intersects = raycaster.intersectObject(plane);
      inpoint = intersects.point;
      final.vertices.push(inpoint);
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

"i" and "k" is always the same. So you are testing if a point is intersecting a plane. Try something like this:

```
var k;  
for (var i = 0; i < vertlen; i++){
    k = i + 1;
    if (k === vertlen) 
    {
      k = 0;
    }
    raycaster.set(vertarray[i], vertarray[k]);
    intersects = raycaster.intersectObject(plane);
    inpoint = intersects.point;
    final.vertices.push(inpoint);    
  }
```

...2 days later  :  what i wrote is wrong. i and k is not always the same. See comments to this post.

Comment: Hi, even trying that my jsfiddle function doesn't seem to work. Once I call this function it only returns to me a black screen. I'm not sure what is wrong in my code. Would you mind taking a look?
http://jsfiddle.net/9LnryfLL/

Comment: Hi, what i wrote is only half rigth. I changed your code. http://jsfiddle.net/9LnryfLL/7/    First i added materials to your objects. The black screen means that there is a code error. You need to look in the console to see what javascript don't like. You are creating way to much faces. And you have to reconsider what rays you realy need to test.